# How to implement &> and &>> in a shell program?

Tags: c, shell, unix

I am implementing my own shell and I have managed to get the I/O redirections working along with pipes. However, I am unable to understand what I should be doing to redirect stderr as well so that I can incorporate the `>&` and `>>&` features as well in my code.

Also, does the logic follow for implementing `|&`?

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>

void execute(char **, int, char **);
void handle_signal(int);
int parse(char *, char **, char **, int *);
void chop(char *);

#define INPUT_STRING_SIZE 80

#define NORMAL              00
#define OUTPUT_REDIRECTION  11
#define INPUT_REDIRECTION   22
#define PIPELINE            33
#define BACKGROUND          44
#define OUTPUT_APP  55

typedef void (*sighandler_t)(int);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i, mode = NORMAL, cmdArgc;
    size_t len = INPUT_STRING_SIZE;
    char *cpt, *inputString, *cmdArgv[INPUT_STRING_SIZE], *supplement = NULL;
    inputString = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*INPUT_STRING_SIZE);

    char curDir[100];

    while(1)
    {
        mode = NORMAL;
        getcwd(curDir, 100);
        printf("%s@%s->", getlogin(),curDir);
        getline( &inputString, &len, stdin);
        if(strcmp(inputString, "exit\n") == 0)
            exit(0);
        cmdArgc = parse(inputString, cmdArgv, &supplement, &mode);
        if(strcmp(*cmdArgv, "cd") == 0)
        {
            chdir(cmdArgv[1]);
        }
        else 
            execute(cmdArgv, mode, &supplement);
    }
    return 0;
}

int parse(char *inputString, char *cmdArgv[], char **supplementPtr, int *modePtr)
{
    int cmdArgc = 0, terminate = 0;
    char *srcPtr = inputString;
    //printf("parse fun%sends", inputString);
    while(*srcPtr != '\0' && terminate == 0)
    {
        *cmdArgv = srcPtr;
        cmdArgc++;
        //printf("parse fun2%sends", *cmdArgv);
        while(*srcPtr != ' ' && *srcPtr != '\t' && *srcPtr != '\0' && *srcPtr != '\n' && terminate == 0)
        {
            switch(*srcPtr)
            {
                case '&':
                    *modePtr = BACKGROUND;
                    break;
                case '>':
                    *modePtr = OUTPUT_REDIRECTION;
                    *cmdArgv = '\0';
                    srcPtr++;
                    if(*srcPtr == '>')
                    {
                        *modePtr = OUTPUT_APP;
                        srcPtr++;
                    }
                    while(*srcPtr == ' ' || *srcPtr == '\t')
                        srcPtr++;
                    *supplementPtr = srcPtr;
                    chop(*supplementPtr);
                    terminate = 1;
                    break;
                case '<':
                    *modePtr = INPUT_REDIRECTION;
                    *cmdArgv = '\0';
                    srcPtr++;
                    while(*srcPtr == ' ' || *srcPtr == '\t')
                        srcPtr++;
                    *supplementPtr = srcPtr;
                    chop(*supplementPtr);
                    terminate = 1;
                    break;
                case '|':
                    *modePtr = PIPELINE;
                    *cmdArgv = '\0';
                    srcPtr++;
                    while(*srcPtr == ' ' || *srcPtr == '\t')
                        srcPtr++;
                    *supplementPtr = srcPtr;
                    //chop(*supplementPtr);
                    terminate = 1;
                    break;
            }
            srcPtr++;
        }
        while((*srcPtr == ' ' || *srcPtr == '\t' || *srcPtr == '\n') && terminate == 0)
        {
            *srcPtr = '\0';
            srcPtr++;
        }
        cmdArgv++;
    }
    /*srcPtr++;
    *srcPtr = '\0';
    destPtr--;*/
    *cmdArgv = '\0';
    return cmdArgc;
}

void chop(char *srcPtr)
{
    while(*srcPtr != ' ' && *srcPtr != '\t' && *srcPtr != '\n')
    {
        srcPtr++;
    }
    *srcPtr = '\0';
}

void execute(char **cmdArgv, int mode, char **supplementPtr)
{
    pid_t pid, pid2;
    FILE *fp;
    int mode2 = NORMAL, cmdArgc, status1, status2;
    char *cmdArgv2[INPUT_STRING_SIZE], *supplement2 = NULL;
    int myPipe[2];
    if(mode == PIPELINE)
    {
        if(pipe(myPipe))                    //create pipe
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Pipe failed!");
            exit(-1);
        }
        parse(*supplementPtr, cmdArgv2, &supplement2, &mode2);
    }
    pid = fork();
    if( pid < 0)
    {
        printf("Error occured");
        exit(-1);
    }
    else if(pid == 0)
    {
        switch(mode)
        {
            case OUTPUT_REDIRECTION:
                fp = fopen(*supplementPtr, "w+");
                dup2(fileno(fp), 1);
                break;
            case OUTPUT_APP:
                fp = fopen(*supplementPtr, "a");
                dup2(fileno(fp), 1);
                break;
            case INPUT_REDIRECTION:
                fp = fopen(*supplementPtr, "r");
                dup2(fileno(fp), 0);
                break;
            case PIPELINE:
                close(myPipe[0]);       //close input of pipe
                dup2(myPipe[1], fileno(stdout));
                close(myPipe[1]);
                break;
        }
        execvp(*cmdArgv, cmdArgv);
    }
    else
    {
        if(mode == BACKGROUND)
            ;
        else if(mode == PIPELINE)
        {
            waitpid(pid, &status1, 0);      //wait for process 1 to finish
            pid2 = fork();
            if(pid2 < 0)
            {
                printf("error in forking");
                exit(-1);
            }
            else if(pid2 == 0)
            {
                close(myPipe[1]);       //close output to pipe
                dup2(myPipe[0], fileno(stdin));
                close(myPipe[0]);
                execvp(*cmdArgv2, cmdArgv2);
            }
            else
            {
                ;//wait(NULL);
                //waitpid(pid, &status1, 0);
                //waitpid(pid2, &status2, 0);
                close(myPipe[0]);
                close(myPipe[1]);
            }
        }
        else
            waitpid(pid, &status1, 0);
            //wait(NULL);
    }
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Ok, so as per the suggestion from Jonathan Leffler, I have modified my code to include the redirections. Now I wanted to see if I could change it a bit, by trying to make the user enter ">&" instead of "&>" and still achieve what ">&" does. The same goes for "&>>" and "&|".

However, when I try to issue the command, say echo hello >& a.txt, I get a file by the name "&" and that file now contains the string hello! I am unsure what is going wrong here. @JonathanLeffler - can you please take a look and suggest what I might be doing wrong? Here is the updated code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>


void execute(char **, int, char **);
void handle_signal(int);
int parse(char *, char **, char **, int *);
void chop(char *);

#define INPUT_STRING_SIZE 80

#define NORMAL              00
#define OUTPUT_REDIRECTION  11
#define INPUT_REDIRECTION   22
#define PIPELINE            33
#define BACKGROUND          44
#define OUTPUT_APP  55
#define OUTPUT_REDIRECTION_WITH_ERROR 66
#define OUTPUT_REDIRECTION_WITH_APPEND_ERROR 77
#define PIPELINE_WITH_ERROR 88


typedef void (*sighandler_t)(int);



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i, mode = NORMAL, cmdArgc;
    size_t len = INPUT_STRING_SIZE;
    char *cpt, *inputString, *cmdArgv[INPUT_STRING_SIZE], *supplement = NULL;
    inputString = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*INPUT_STRING_SIZE);

    char curDir[100];

    while(1)
    {
        mode = NORMAL;
        getcwd(curDir, 100);
        printf("%s@%s->", getlogin(),curDir);
        getline( &inputString, &len, stdin);
        if(strcmp(inputString, "exit\n") == 0)
            exit(0);
        cmdArgc = parse(inputString, cmdArgv, &supplement, &mode);
        if(strcmp(*cmdArgv, "cd") == 0)
        {
            chdir(cmdArgv[1]);
        }
        else 
            execute(cmdArgv, mode, &supplement);
    }
    return 0;
}

int parse(char *inputString, char *cmdArgv[], char **supplementPtr, int *modePtr)
{
    int cmdArgc = 0, terminate = 0;
    char *srcPtr = inputString;
    //printf("parse fun%sends", inputString);
    while(*srcPtr != '\0' && terminate == 0)
    {
        *cmdArgv = srcPtr;
        cmdArgc++;
        //printf("parse fun2%sends", *cmdArgv);
        while(*srcPtr != ' ' && *srcPtr != '\t' && *srcPtr != '\0' && *srcPtr != '\n' && terminate == 0)
        {
            switch(*srcPtr)
            {
            /*  case '&':
                    *modePtr = BACKGROUND;
                    break; */
                case '>':
                    *modePtr = OUTPUT_REDIRECTION;
                    *cmdArgv = '\0';
                    srcPtr++;
                    if(*srcPtr == '>')
                    {
                        *modePtr = OUTPUT_APP;
                        srcPtr++;
                    }
                    else if(*srcPtr == '>&')
                    {
                        *modePtr = OUTPUT_REDIRECTION_WITH_ERROR;
                        srcPtr++;
                    }
                    else if(*srcPtr == '>>&')
                    {
                        *modePtr = OUTPUT_REDIRECTION_WITH_APPEND_ERROR;
                        srcPtr++;
                    }
                    while(*srcPtr == ' ' || *srcPtr == '\t')
                        srcPtr++;
                    *supplementPtr = srcPtr;
                    chop(*supplementPtr);
                    terminate = 1;
                    break;
                case '<':
                    *modePtr = INPUT_REDIRECTION;
                    *cmdArgv = '\0';
                    srcPtr++;
                    while(*srcPtr == ' ' || *srcPtr == '\t')
                        srcPtr++;
                    *supplementPtr = srcPtr;
                    chop(*supplementPtr);
                    terminate = 1;
                    break;
                case '|':
                    *modePtr = PIPELINE;
                    *cmdArgv = '\0';
                    srcPtr++;
                    if(*srcPtr == '|')
                    {
                        *modePtr = PIPELINE;
                        srcPtr++;
                    }
                    else if(*srcPtr == '|&')
                    {
                        *modePtr = PIPELINE_WITH_ERROR;
                        srcPtr++;
                    }
                    while(*srcPtr == ' ' || *srcPtr == '\t')
                        srcPtr++;
                    *supplementPtr = srcPtr;
                    //chop(*supplementPtr);
                    terminate = 1;
                    break;
            }
            srcPtr++;
        }
        while((*srcPtr == ' ' || *srcPtr == '\t' || *srcPtr == '\n') && terminate == 0)
        {
            *srcPtr = '\0';
            srcPtr++;
        }
        cmdArgv++;
    }
    /*srcPtr++;
    *srcPtr = '\0';
    destPtr--;*/
    *cmdArgv = '\0';
    return cmdArgc;
}

void chop(char *srcPtr)
{
    while(*srcPtr != ' ' && *srcPtr != '\t' && *srcPtr != '\n')
    {
        srcPtr++;
    }
    *srcPtr = '\0';
}

void execute(char **cmdArgv, int mode, char **supplementPtr)
{
    pid_t pid, pid2;
    FILE *fp;
    int mode2 = NORMAL, cmdArgc, status1, status2;
    char *cmdArgv2[INPUT_STRING_SIZE], *supplement2 = NULL;
    int myPipe[2];
    if(mode == PIPELINE)
    {
        if(pipe(myPipe))                    //create pipe
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Pipe failed!");
            exit(-1);
        }
        parse(*supplementPtr, cmdArgv2, &supplement2, &mode2);
    }
    pid = fork();
    if( pid < 0)
    {
        printf("Error occured");
        exit(-1);
    }
    else if(pid == 0)
    {
        switch(mode)
        {
            case OUTPUT_REDIRECTION:
                fp = fopen(*supplementPtr, "w+");
                dup2(fileno(fp), 1);
                break;
            case OUTPUT_REDIRECTION_WITH_ERROR:
                fp = fopen(*supplementPtr, "w+");
                dup2(fileno(fp), 1);
                dup2(2, 1);
                break;
            case OUTPUT_REDIRECTION_WITH_APPEND_ERROR:
                fp = fopen(*supplementPtr, "a");
                dup2(fileno(fp), 1);
                dup2(2, 1);
                break;
            case OUTPUT_APP:
                fp = fopen(*supplementPtr, "a");
                dup2(fileno(fp), 1);
                break;
            case INPUT_REDIRECTION:
                fp = fopen(*supplementPtr, "r");
                dup2(fileno(fp), 0);
                break;
            case PIPELINE:
                close(myPipe[0]);       //close input of pipe
                dup2(myPipe[1], fileno(stdout));
                close(myPipe[1]);
                break;
            case PIPELINE_WITH_ERROR:
                close(myPipe[0]);
                dup2(myPipe[1], 1);
                dup2(2, 1);
                close(myPipe[1]);
                break;
        }
        execvp(*cmdArgv, cmdArgv);
    }
    else
    {
        if(mode == BACKGROUND)
            ;
        else if(mode == PIPELINE)
        {
            waitpid(pid, &status1, 0);      //wait for process 1 to finish
            pid2 = fork();
            if(pid2 < 0)
            {
                printf("error in forking");
                exit(-1);
            }
            else if(pid2 == 0)
            {
                close(myPipe[1]);       //close output to pipe
                dup2(myPipe[0], fileno(stdin));
                close(myPipe[0]);
                execvp(*cmdArgv2, cmdArgv2);
            }
            else
            {
                ;//wait(NULL);
                //waitpid(pid, &status1, 0);
                //waitpid(pid2, &status2, 0);
                close(myPipe[0]);
                close(myPipe[1]);
            }
        }
        else
            waitpid(pid, &status1, 0);
            //wait(NULL);
    }
}
```

Comment: Study the source code of some existing free shell, like [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With all the I/O redirections, the operations are straight-forward manipulations of file descriptors.  The key function is [`dup2()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html).

The `>&2` notation redirects standard output (file descriptor, fd, 1) to standard error (fd = 2):

```
dup2(2, 1);
```

This makes the existing open file descriptor 2 and the (not necessarily open) file descriptor 1 refer to the same descriptor.  (I got the arguments back to front in the first edition of this answer; also in the next call to `dup2()`, but the final two were correct.)

The `&>` notation redirects standard error to the same place as standard output:

```
dup2(1, 2);
```

With pipes (`|&`), you first do:

```
pipe(pair);
…fork()…
…in the writer…
dup2(pair[1], 1);
dup2(1, 2);
close(pair[0]);
close(pair[1]);
```

With the `>>` notation, you open the file in append mode and then use `dup2()`.

---

> Can these be done using `dup()` instead of `dup2()`? and if so, how would it have to be done?

Yes, in much the same way you can do mathematics with Peano Arithmetic.  It's hard and why bother?

The difference is that `dup()` duplicates the descriptor to the lowest available descriptor.  So, assuming that standard input (0) and standard output (1) are open, you can simulate:

```
dup2(1, 2);
```

with:

```
close(2);
dup(1);
```

As long as you're only dealing with descriptors up to, say, 5, this is manageable.  However, `dup2()` is much easier to use; it duplicates to the specified descriptor even if there are closed descriptors less than the target one.

---

#### Fixing the updated code

> Can you please take a look at my updated question above and suggest what I might be doing incorrectly?

The first thing I do when given a request like that is compile it (copied verbatim from the question) under my usual set of compiler warning flags, and in this case, the warnings (converted to errors by the `-Werror` option) are both plentiful and serious.  If you're not compiling and seeing such warnings, you are making your life harder than it need be!

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Werror    pipes-22585525.c -o pipes-22585525
pipes-22585525.c: In function ‘main’:
pipes-22585525.c:45:9: error: implicit declaration of function ‘strcmp’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
         if(strcmp(inputString, "exit\n") == 0)
         ^
pipes-22585525.c:34:11: error: unused variable ‘cpt’ [-Werror=unused-variable]
     char *cpt, *inputString, *cmdArgv[INPUT_STRING_SIZE], *supplement = NULL;
           ^
pipes-22585525.c:32:27: error: variable ‘cmdArgc’ set but not used [-Werror=unused-but-set-variable]
     int i, mode = NORMAL, cmdArgc;
                           ^
pipes-22585525.c:32:9: error: unused variable ‘i’ [-Werror=unused-variable]
     int i, mode = NORMAL, cmdArgc;
         ^
pipes-22585525.c:30:14: error: unused parameter ‘argc’ [-Werror=unused-parameter]
 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
              ^
pipes-22585525.c:30:26: error: unused parameter ‘argv’ [-Werror=unused-parameter]
 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
                          ^
pipes-22585525.c: In function ‘parse’:
pipes-22585525.c:84:40: error: multi-character character constant [-Werror=multichar]
                     else if(*srcPtr == '>&')
                                        ^
pipes-22585525.c:84:21: error: comparison is always false due to limited range of data type [-Werror=type-limits]
                     else if(*srcPtr == '>&')
                     ^
pipes-22585525.c:89:40: error: multi-character character constant [-Werror=multichar]
                     else if(*srcPtr == '>>&')
                                        ^
pipes-22585525.c:89:21: error: comparison is always false due to limited range of data type [-Werror=type-limits]
                     else if(*srcPtr == '>>&')
                     ^
pipes-22585525.c:119:40: error: multi-character character constant [-Werror=multichar]
                     else if(*srcPtr == '|&')
                                        ^
pipes-22585525.c:119:21: error: comparison is always false due to limited range of data type [-Werror=type-limits]
                     else if(*srcPtr == '|&')
                     ^
pipes-22585525.c: In function ‘execute’:
pipes-22585525.c:160:43: error: unused variable ‘status2’ [-Werror=unused-variable]
     int mode2 = NORMAL, cmdArgc, status1, status2;
                                           ^
pipes-22585525.c:160:25: error: unused variable ‘cmdArgc’ [-Werror=unused-variable]
     int mode2 = NORMAL, cmdArgc, status1, status2;
                         ^
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
$
```

The warnings about `argc` and `argv` can be avoided by using `int main(void)` until you actually parse the arguments passed to your shell. The warning for `strcmp()` is fixed by including `<string.h>`.  The other unused variable warnings should likewise be fixed.  They're mundane issues but should be fixed so the code compiles warning free.

The other set of warnings is exemplified by:

```
pipes-22585525.c: In function ‘parse’:
pipes-22585525.c:84:40: error: multi-character character constant [-Werror=multichar]
                     else if(*srcPtr == '>&')
                                        ^
pipes-22585525.c:84:21: error: comparison is always false due to limited range of data type [-Werror=type-limits]
```

The variable `srcPtr` is a `char *`; it can only hold a single character at a time.  The multi-character constants are permitted but have an implementation-defined value.  The only thing you can be sure of is that a single character can never hold a value `'>&'`, which is what the second of the messages tells you.  The first message is hinting that you should be writing:

```
                     else if (strncmp(srcPtr, ">&", 2) == 0)
```

There is a caveat with that.  Suppose that the symbol was `"<<"`; in Bash, there's also a symbol `"<<<"`.  It would be crucial to test for `"<<<"` before testing for `"<<"` because otherwise you'd never see the longer symbol because the shorter would always match.  Likewise with the redirections; you need to be careful to ensure that no early test precludes detecting one of the later symbols.

Fix those problems and you'll probably well on the way to resolving your problems.  Ping again if you're still stuck.  (Oh, and I've seen programs that produce reams more warnings when first subjected to my stringent compilation options — it isn't bad code.  But since the compiler can tell you what you're doing wrong, you're wasting your time (and arguably mine, but this will help you for the future) by not having the compiler tell you what's wrong.  Remember, it knows more about C than you do!)

I use those compiler options, or minor variants thereupon, with essentially all my C code.  Most of it also compiles and runs correctly under a C++ compiler, but that's a hair-shirt I choose to wear and you don't have to.

Comment: I think you flipped the arguments to `dup2`

Comment: thanks a lot guys! I will try this out and comment if this works for me or if I am still stuck ... appreciate all the help!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Can these be done using dup() instead of dup2()? and if so, how would it have to be done ? I am just asking so that I understand the difference between the usage of these functions ....

Comment: Thanks for the gr8 explanation! I will try to code this and check if it works for me .... will resolve it soon if I can get it to work ... :)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - Can you please take a look at my updated question above and suggest what I might be doing incorrectly? Appreciate your advice thus far!

Comment: @user2784743: see the update 'Fixing the updated code'.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - Thanks a ton for the help! However, I got the code to work with a slight tweak from my side. I was thinking about it through the day today and it struck me. I tried it out and it worked. Thanks for all the assistance! I have resolved the question too .... :)